# Adding Comments to File

Tags: bash, shell, unix

We have two files file1.txt and file2.txt

file1.txt

```
PropertyA
PropertyB
PropertyC
####Some Comments##
PropertyA
PropertyB
PropertyC
PropertyD
```

file2.txt

```
#This is Property A
PropertyA=valueforpropertyA

PropertyB=valueforpropertyB
#Adding values to Property C
PropertyC=valueforpropertyC
#Value for Property D
PropertyD=valueforpropertyD
#This is Property E
PropertyE=valueforpropertyE

PropertyF=valueforpropertyF
#End of Properties
#End of values
#End of Files
```

Using the below command we used to write the values to file1.txt from file2.txt after the properties appearing in ####Some Comments## section of file1.txt.

```
awk -F'=' 'FNR==NR{if (p) a[$0]; else {print; if ($0 ~ /####Some Comments##/) p=1} next}
  $1 in a' file1.txt file2.txt > _file1.txt && mv _file1.txt file1.txt
```

This is the output:

```
PropertyA
PropertyB
PropertyC
####Some Comments##
PropertyA=valueforpropertyA
PropertyB=valueforpropertyB
PropertyC=valueforpropertyC
PropertyD=valueforpropertyD
```

We need the above command to print out the comments that are appearing in file2.txt also. This should be the output of file1.txt

```
*PropertyA
PropertyB
PropertyC
####Some Comments##
#This is Property A
PropertyA=valueforpropertyA
PropertyB=valueforpropertyB
#Adding values to Property C
PropertyC=valueforpropertyC
#Value for Property D
PropertyD=valueforpropertyD
#End of Properties
#End of values
#End of Files*
```

How can this be done using the above command?

Comment: Some obfuscated awk code.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F'=' 'FNR==NR{if (p) a[$0]; else {print; if ($0 ~ /####Some Comments##/) p=1} next} { if($1 in a) { print a[$1] } else if ($1 ~ /^#/){ print }}' file1.txt file2.txt > _file1.txt && mv _file1.txt file1.txt
```

Try this....

I just added an extra bracket which prints the line wether the a-array contains $1 or not (if not, its a comment)

Comment: Hi Joda,

Thanks for your reply,

I have tried your command. However, getting error message unexpected newline or end of string //{ print }//

awk: cmd. line:1: FNR==NR{if (p) a[$0]; else {print; if ($0 ~ /####Some Comments##/) p=1} next} { if($1 in a) { print a[$1] } else if ($1 ~ /^#/){ print }
awk: cmd. line:1:                                                                                                                                         ^ unexpected newline or end of string

Comment: Thiis is my command: awk -F'=' 'FNR==NR{if (p) a[$0]; else {print; if ($0 ~ /####Some Comments##/) p=1} next} { if($1 in a) { print a[$1] } else if ($1 ~ /^#/){ print }' file1.txt file2.txt > _file1.txt && mv _file1.txt file1.txt. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Ups, i missed a "}" at the end :) I edited my answer